# TNS: Listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, tns

I am able to connect to database using sqlplus /nolog but SQL Developer throws the below error when I connect to it
[image]

here are my configuration in tnsnames.ora
[image]

and listener.ora
[image]

Comment: `sqlplus /nolog` does not connect you to anything. Make sure your database is actually started.

Comment: Hi @Mat I can connect to db using conn

Comment: Please show us the command using which you are able to connect and also show us the configurations of sql developer connection which refuses to connect.

Answer (score 1):

SQL /nolog does not connect to database.
If you are able to connect using conn then need to see parameter passed while connecting database in SQL developer
Which connection type are you using while connecting using SQL developer?
Are you having multiple oracle homes on the server if yes then check which home you are pointing to.